# How to generate login code with expiration in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm setting up a website using Node.js Express and MongoDB that allow user register and login and it's work nice and no issue with it. But now i want to generate multiple login code (something like a coupon code) with an expiration date so user can only use it once. and if the login code expired, user cannot login anymore. Is there a way to do that?

[image: expected login form]

I was looking authentication strategy on passportjs but i cannot find any of it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

For setting this up with mongo with a schema like `{ createdAt: timestamp, code: string }`

1. Create a unique index on `code` so that you can't create the same code twice. In client-side code, you'll end up needing to retry creating some codes. (You could instead pre-generate codes & put them into a queue and pull them off, but that sounds a little bit more complicated)
2. Add a TTL index on `createdAt` for expiration to automatically remove the documents. If you instead want to "expire" the documents but track that the code used to exist, you'd need to manually check the timestamp.
3. When a code is used, you'll want to delete it (or mark it as used).
4. You'll likely want to include some sort of rate-limiting by ip so that people can't brute force codes.

With passport, you'll want to specify a "custom" strategy. With a custom strategy, you can do anything you'd like to set up authentication. [Passport-js How to create a custom strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277756/passport-js-how-to-create-a-custom-strategy) has a little bit of guidance.